# Creating input type=button

Tags: theming, 8, forms

was tying to create a `<input type="button" />` in drupal 8, below code snippet

```
$button['button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => $this->t('#Clear'),
);
```

followed by

```
render($button)
```

It's not working as expected. An input type submit is being created instead.

[image]

I have also check the example module for D8 [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples), same thing occurs here.

How do I create an input `type=button`, any help ? , or am I doing some thing wrong ?